# C++ reading from a .txt file line by line string and number data type on each line

Tags: c++, fstream

So I am trying to read a .txt file in c++ program. Each line in the text file has firstName, lastName and yearlySalary (e,g, Tomm Dally, 120000).
I can seem to read a file properly - it skips the first column (firstName) and stops reading the data in after first line. Why is that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string fName;
    string lName;
    double yearlyPay;
    double backPayDue;
    double newAnualSalary;
    double newMonthlyWage;
    int numOfEmployees = 0;
    double totalBackPayDue = 0;

    ifstream empSalariesOld("EmpSalaries.txt");
    ofstream empSalariesNew("EmpSalariesNew.txt");
    if (!empSalariesOld.fail())
    {
        while (empSalariesOld >> fName)
        {
            empSalariesOld >> fName >> lName >> yearlyPay;
            std::cout << fName << " " << lName << " " << yearlyPay << endl;
            numOfEmployees++;
        }

    }

    empSalariesOld.close();
    empSalariesNew.close();


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a pen, and trace the execution of the code, line by line. Pop quiz: How many times  will the shown code attempt to read `fName` from the file, before moving onto `lName`? The answer should be 1. But it's not.

Comment: in the lab sheet teacher suggested to use getline(istream, string) but I dont want the number to be in the string

Comment: Well, you should actually listen to your teacher, because that's the better approach.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c

Comment: the text file has 3 lines

Comment: This read: `empSalariesOld >> fName >> lName >> yearlyPay;` is not checked. It can fail and the results will be used regardless. Solving this problem will likely solve the one you are asking about.

Comment: No, re-read the first comment. Well, yes that too.

Answer (score 1):

### You are not reading the lines correctly.

When your `while` statement calls `empSalariesOld >> fName` for the first time, it reads an employee's *first name*.  Then, inside the loop body, when you call `empSalariesOld >> fName >> lName >> yearlyPay`, `>> fName` reads the employee's *last name* (because you already read the *first* name), then `>> lName` reads the employee's *salary*, and `>> yearlyPay` tries to read the next employee's *first name* and fails!

Try something more like the following instead.  Use `std::getline()` to read a whole line, and then use `std::istringstream` to parse it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string fName;
    string lName;
    double yearlyPay;
    //...
    int numOfEmployees = 0;

    ifstream empSalariesOld("EmpSalaries.txt");
    ofstream empSalariesNew("EmpSalariesNew.txt");

    if (empSalariesOld)
    {
        string line;
        while (getline(empSalariesOld, line))
        {
            istringstream iss(line);
            if (iss >> fName >> lName >> yearlyPay) {
                std::cout << fName << " " << lName << " " << yearlyPay << endl;
                ++numOfEmployees;
            }
        }
    }

    empSalariesOld.close();
    empSalariesNew.close();

    cout << "Press any key";
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

However, if the lines actually have a comma between the name and salary like you showed (`Tomm Dally, 120000`), then try the following instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;
    double yearlyPay;
    //...
    int numOfEmployees = 0;

    ifstream empSalariesOld("EmpSalaries.txt");
    ofstream empSalariesNew("EmpSalariesNew.txt");

    if (empSalariesOld)
    {
        string line;
        while (getline(empSalariesOld, line))
        {
            istringstream iss(line);
            if (getline(iss, name, ',') && (iss >> yearlyPay))
                std::cout << name << " " << yearlyPay << endl;
                ++numOfEmployees;
            }
        }
    }

    empSalariesOld.close();
    empSalariesNew.close();

    cout << "Press any key";
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```